# How to extract data from this .txt files and put the data into pandas dataframe by columns (like 'Report', 'Findings', 'Impression', 'Recomendation')

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

[Radiology Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzFur.png)

I am trying to extract the data by the subject ('findings', 'impression') and trying to put it on pandas dataframe

Comment: Are the subjects the same for every text file? If so, extract text in each subject using string methods such as split and save it as the dataframe. Anyway, you should show your sample text file which can be reproducible not as an image.

Comment: The data on the text file is like as below: And most of the file format is same:                                            ''''''''''''' FINAL REPORT
 EXAMINATION:  CHEST (PORTABLE AP)
 
 INDICATION:  ___ year old woman with cough neutropenic // r/o infection
 
 TECHNIQUE:  Single frontal view of the chest
 
 COMPARISON:  Chest radiograph from ___, ___.
 
 FINDINGS: 
 
 Right subclavian catheter tip terminates in the lower SVC.  Cardiac size is
 normal. The lungs are clear. There is no pneumothorax or pleural effusion.
 
 IMPRESSION: 
 
 No evidence of pneumonia. '''''''''''''

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code with two text files (text1, text2) and subjects (Indication, comparision, findings, and impression.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

text1 = '''FINAL REPORT EXAMINATION: CHEST (PORTABLE AP) INDICATION: ___ year old woman with cough neutropenic // r/o infection TECHNIQUE: Single frontal view of the chest COMPARISON: Chest radiograph from ___, ___. FINDINGS: Right subclavian catheter tip terminates in the lower SVC. Cardiac size is normal. The lungs are clear. There is no pneumothorax or pleural effusion. IMPRESSION: No evidence of pneumonia. '''
text2 = '''FINAL REPORT EXAMINATION: CHEST (PORTABLE AP) INDICATION: ___ year old woman with cough neutropenic // r/o infection TECHNIQUE: Single frontal view of the chest COMPARISON: Chest radiograph from ___, ___. FINDINGS: Right subclavian catheter tip terminates in the lower SVC. Cardiac size is normal. The lungs are clear. There is no pneumothorax or pleural effusion. IMPRESSION: No evidence of pneumonia. '''

subjects = ("INDICATION", "COMPARISON", "FINDINGS", "IMPRESSION")

data = [re.split('|'.join(subjects), text)[1:] for text in [text1, text2]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = subjects)
```

the data is as follows.

```
INDICATION  COMPARISON  FINDINGS    IMPRESSION
0   : ___ year old woman with cough neutropenic //...   : Chest radiograph from ___, ___.   : Right subclavian catheter tip terminates in ...   : No evidence of pneumonia.
1   : ___ year old woman with cough neutropenic //...   : Chest radiograph from ___, ___.   : Right subclavian catheter tip terminates in ...   : No evidence of pneumonia.
```

Comment: ['FINAL REPORT\n', 'INDICATION:  ___ year old woman with cirrhosis.\n', '\n', 'TECHNIQUE:  Frontal chest radiographs were obtained with the patient in the\n', 'upright position.\n', '\n', 'COMPARISON:  Radiographs from ___, ___ and ___.\n', '\n', 'FINDINGS: \n', '\n', 'The lungs are clear of focal consolidation, pleural effusion or pneumothorax. \n', 'The heart size is normal.  The mediastinal contours are normal. Multiple\n', 'surgical clips project over the left breast, and old left rib fractures are\n', 'noted.\n', '\n', 'IMPRESSION: \n', '\n', 'No acute cardiopulmonary process.\n']

Comment: After extracting data from *.txt file, i am getting a list object like above, not a string. Will you help me to extract data from above list object on the same format.

Comment: How you read the file? If the file name is "file", then use text = open("file", "r").read()

Comment: text = []
with open("/content/filename.txt") as f:
      
      [text.append(i.strip(' ')) for i in f.readlines()]
     
      print(text)

Comment: Your file reading code isn't solving the problem , if possible please help. Giving below error with the whole code.   ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns